# Translate this request from Bash to Python?

Tags: python, bash, curl, python-requests

I was given a request in Bash and I have to translate it to Python 2.7. I did this kind of translations several times, but now I am not able to make it work and I do not understand why.

First of all, I was given this Bash request:

```
curl -X POST -v -u user@domain:password --data "@file.json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://destination_url_a
```

With the file *file.json*, whose content is the following one:

```
{
   "username":"user@domain",
   "password":"password",
   "shortName":"a-short-name",
   "visibility":"PRIVATE",
   "sitePreset":"site-dashboard",
   "title":"A Title",
   "description":"A description."
}
```

**If I execute the Bash line in my computer, the result is succesful.**

As always, I tried to use `requests` library in Python to make it work. What I did is:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json

data = {
   "username": "user@domain",
   "password": "password",
   "shortName": "a-short-name",
   "visibility": "PRIVATE",
   "sitePreset": "site-dashboard",
   "title": "A Title",
   "description": "A description.",
}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
data_json = json.dumps(data)

r = requests.post(
    url='http://destination_url_a',
    data=data_json,
    headers=headers,
    auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user@domain', 'password'),
    verify=False,
)
```

Unfortunately, the response, stored in `r` variable, is an error, despite the status code is `200`.

What could be happening? Does anyone find a problem in my code or has any idea?

**EDIT**

However, this is another example very similar which worked perfectly:

**Bash:**

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST --data "@file.json"  -u user@domain:password http://destination_url_b
```

**My Python code**

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json

data = {
   "userName": "user@domain",
   "password": "password",
   "firstName": "Firstname",
   "lastName": "Lastname",
   "email": "email@domain.com",
   "disableAccount": "False",
   "quota": -1,
   "groups": ["a_group",],
}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
data_json = json.dumps(data)

r = requests.post(
    url='http://destination_url_b',
    data=data_json,
    headers=headers,
    auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user@domain', 'password'),
    verify=False,
)
```

It seems to be almost the same to the other request, but this works. Different data is sent, and to a different subdomain (both are sent to the same domain). Will these modifications be important if we are talking about the `User-Agent` you mentioned?

Comment: They look the same. The only differences according to http://httpbin.org/post are the user agent and `"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"` from `requests`.

Comment: Do you really need to send `auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user@domain', 'password')` as this data is already present in your `JSON`? Also, you don't have to specify `'Content-Type'`... Is there any information from response that could help to identify problem?

Comment: @Andersson some web servers will require the content type header, and it won't be specified automatically here since OP is using the `data` argument, not `json`.

Comment: Instead of `data=json.dumps(data)` have you tried `json=data`?

Comment: Thank you all! I am not using `json` argument because it will not work if the server library is not updated to a recent version. To be sure, I use `data` and specify that the content type is JSON through the `headers` argument. I have to specify user and password in `auth` and also send them in the JSON because they are playing different functionalities. I receive an empty answer with status code 200.

Comment: @forvas, your first request parameter `"username"` !=  `"userName"` from second request. Could this affect on how the server parse your data?

Comment: @Andersson great appreciation, I thought that was going to be the reason but not, the result is the same, and the Bash command works well with both `username` or `userName` keys.

Comment: You clain that your Python listigns are complete, but you don't import HTTPBasicAuth on these listings. With code that can't be seen it is hard to spot where there is a problem.

Comment: @jsbueno I forgot to copy that line from the beginning of my file, my code is long and I tried to paste the relevant part with non-confusing examples of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, there was no error in the code neither in the User-Agent.

The problem was that the destination application did not accept sites with the same short-name value.

What I was doing is creating the site from Bash, which worked, then removing it from the interface of the app and trying to create it from Python with the same data. I was getting error when doing that because in spite of having removed the site, I had to remove some residual data of it from the trashcan of the app too. If not, app returned an error since it considered that the site I was trying to create already existed.

So if I had introduced different short-name in each attempt, I would not have had any error.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, webservices filter on user-agent. User agent of curl and python are different. That may explain.
Try to forge a "legitimate" user-agent by modifying the request header.